# How to control widgets position insid QStackedLayout

Tags: qt

I've created a QStackedLayout in which I added 2 buttons, but I want to shift one button to the right corner insted of the left corner as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

What I've done so far:

```
    QStackedLayout *stackedLayout = new QStackedLayout;
    stackedLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton_2);
    stackedLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton);
    stackedLayout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);
```

Answer (score -1):

Place the QPushbutton in a container (i.e. QWidget) that allows it to be centered with an additional layout.

Comment: I've done it before and it's a solution but then all the upper part of the "Test" button will no longer be functional because it will be behind that container

Comment: @temp If you tried this solution before but had problems then please edit your question to show the code and explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve and the problems encountered.

Comment: @G.M. It was all mainly in the designer, as I placed the "X" button inside a widget with a Horizontal layout along with a spacer and then in the code insted of ```stackedLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton_2);``` I place ```stackedLayout->addWidget(ui->widget);```

Comment: @temp, you should really be more specific, add your code if you want some help...

Answer (score -1):

If I understand properly, you want a QPushButton above an other. The one above must be smaller and at the top right corner?

```
 QVBoxLayout * vlayout_PB_under = new QVBoxLayout();
 QHBoxLayout * hlayout_PB_under = new QHBoxLayout();

 QPushButton * PB_x = new QPushButton("X",this);
 QPushButton * PB_test = new QPushButton("test",this);

 PB_x ->setFixedSize(20,20);
 PB_test ->setFixedSize(200,200);

 PB_test ->setLayout(vlayout_PB_under );
 vlayout_PB_under ->addLayout(hlayout_PB_under);
 hlayout_PB_under->addWidget(PB_x );

 vlayout_PB_under ->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
 hlayout_PB_under->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop );
```

The purpose of a QStackLayout is to allow switching easily the visible widget at a same position, not to display at the same time multiple widget...

Read the documentation : "**where only one widget is visible at a time**"